# commit multi modules maven project to gitlab

Tags: eclipse, maven, gitlab

I am developing a multimodules maven project on eclipse.
I would like commit on gitlab project. The project has 1 parent module and 3 childs modules.

First I cloned a empty gitlab project, then I created the maven project under my git folder on local pc.

I tried a commit and on stage section there is whole project modules,parents and child. The parents module contains the sources of the child modules.

How can I commit my project on gitlab?
It is possible select the file to commit on the project tree?

Thank you....

Comment: "The parents module contains the sources of the child modules". Really?

Comment: Yes...there are all the sources...

Comment: This goes against Maven. You should seriously think about adjusting your project structure.

Comment: I created the parent project first ,using  maven->project eclipse option,  and than  every single child project with maven->module eclipse option for the childes.....

Comment: But then, the sources should be in the separate module folders

Comment: yes, but are visible on the parent project too....